# Responsive Carousel for height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been fooling with this carousel for days. I am trying to make it responsive in the height but it keeps getting messed up and stretched real long. I read many things and tried many different techniques. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong so hopefully I can move on from this lovely carousel or start actually putting images into it. The media queries were a last experiment for me and basically I just want it to resize proportionally on mobile and I am not quite sure of the screen size for that. I am guessing if my images are going to be sized to 1024 by 700 that I should use 700 height for medium and anything larger??

```
<div class="container">     
<div id="portfolio">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<h1 class="display-3">Portfolio</h1>
<p class="lead">Here are some examples of my latest works.</p>

<div id="carouselPortfolio" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" 
class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<!-- Images -->
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block" src="http://www.placehold.it/1024x700" alt="First 
slide">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Business Cards</h3>
<p>Here are some business cards I have made.</p></div></div>

<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block" src="http://www.placehold.it/1024x700" alt="Second 
slide">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>First Website in 1997</h3>
<p>I ran one of the top Mariah Carey fansites for six years (1998-2003) and 
got to meet Mariah Carey multiple times, got 20+ autogaphs, got personal 
phone messages from Mariah to put on my website and I enjoyed updating it on 
a daily basis.</p></div></div>

<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block" src="http://www.placehold.it/1024x700" alt="Third 
slide">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Billboard Designs</h3>
<p>I worked with SSMarketing Solutions and designed various marketing 
materials for her clients. I got the chance to design and illustrate two of 
their billboards that appeared on main highways in New Jersey.</p></div>
</div>

</div><!--Carousel Inner-->
</div><!--Carousel Example Slides Only--> 

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselPortfolio" role="button" 
data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>

<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselPortfolio" role="button" 
data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>

</div><!--column-->
</div> <!--row-->
</div><!-- Scrollspy -->
```

CSS:
/* Carousel */

```
#carouselPortfolio img {
min-height: 300px;
min-width: 100%;
}

#carouselPortfolio > .carousel-indicators > li {
border-radius: 0px;
min-width: 25px;
min-height: 10px;
background-color: #9d9d9d;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

#carouselPortfolio > .carousel-indicators > .active {
background-color: #5b9ed5;
}

#carouselPortfolio .carousel-caption {
color: black;
text-align: center;
top: auto;
}

#carouselPortfolio .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
max-width: 1024px;
max-height: 740px;
margin: auto;
}

/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
.carousel-inner {
 max-height: 200px; 
}
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { 
.carousel-inner {
 max-height: 700px; 
}
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min){ 
.carousel-inner {
 max-height: 700px; 
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4? The media queries show LESS variables but Bootstrap 4 is SASS.

Comment: Yes I am using Bootstrap 4. Will the media queries work if I do the SASS version of them? I didn't know there was a difference. I have only been coding for about 2 months now. I guess I have a lot to learn :)

Comment: They won't work unless you're using a SASS processor.

Comment: Do I need media queries to make my height responsive?